# Use document.ready or not when loading external data from an aJax call?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, performance

Working on a page to load an external data file via JS and display the contents within PRE tags.  Its working, but a friend mentioned I should use always use document.ready() function.

why is it needed?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
    <meta http-equiv='expires' content='-1'>
    <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            var ajaxRq = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            ajaxRq.open("GET", "data.txt", false);
            ajaxRq.send(null);
            document.write(ajaxRq.responseText);
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<pre><script>myFunction();</script></pre>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you need document ready?  The page is already loaded.

Comment: Also you're not using jQuery at all.  So pulling in jQuery just for document ready would be overkill.

Comment: See your point... adding that doesn't make much sense.  Is there anything else you would improve, or just leave as-is?

Comment: Additionally, there's no need for using `XMLHttpRequest`, let alone `ActiveX` unless you're targeting really old browsers. `fetch` exists